# How long do tiny spiders live?

Tags: entomology, death, human-ear, lifespan

I'm pretty sure there's a spider in my ear. I feel it move and hear the scratching (i blame my cat for playing with bugs in the bed). I've gone to the doctor, but all they do is flush my ear with water and it never works. I've decide to just wait for the damned thing to die.

How long will it live in my ear without coming out? How quickly will it die if i flush my ears with peroxide once a day?

any other advice for how to get the stupid thing out?

Comment: Unfortunately this is for all it's worth a personal medical question, which is not on scope for this site. Please don't do anything yourself without asking a doctor. If the last one did not help you, try to go to a specialist. Still, be open for the suggestion that it might be there is nothing alive in your ear.

Comment: Maybe lure it out of hiding with a fly? Scare it away with a big bird? Smoke it out? Play nasty music?

Comment: It's not a spider. It might be a paresthesia (more specifically, formication) that you're experiencing, though. Spiders don't survive flushing, or peroxide. I often used to see kids with insects in their ears in the ED. Never did any of them remain after flushing. Interestingly, my son once got a spider in his ear. I did get it out with flushing. There's another possibility: a bit of fluid in the middle ear.

Comment: I was asking how long it would take to die. The doc i did see DID say there was something moving in my ear. There are no other doctors who will take my insurance in my area, so he's the only one i can see. When nothing came out after the water attempts (and 5 hours of it mind you) he just said 'oh well, go home' essentially. Hence why i'm asking //how long it would take for a spider to die stuck in an ear./// I know the ear is self-cleaning and the wax will just push it out eventually. I need to know how long it'll take.

Comment: @anongoodnurse wow.... I removed that comment I really thought this was impossible...

Comment: If there's something stuck in your ear after five hours of flushing, you need to see a better doctor. Hardened ear wax is dark and can be hard to remove, and can mess with your hearing.

Comment: Did it die yet?